# Uniqueness of $p$-adic valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $n$ is an integer strictly greater than zero. Then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is finite: hence, it it possesses a composition series $(G_i)_{0\leq i\leq m}$ such that 
$$n=[G_0:G_1]\ldots[G_{m-1}:G_m].$$ 
Letting $P$ denote the set of primes, there exists a mapping 
$$u:P\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
such that

1. $\{p\in P\ |\ u(p)\ne0\}$ is finite;
2. $n=\prod_{p\in P}p^{u(p)}$.

I would like to show that $u$ is unique. But I am not sure how to start this proof. I can begin by supposing that there exists another mapping 
$v:P\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ satisfying (1) and (2). But I cannot figure out what to do next..

Comment: This is a rephrasing of the [unique prime-factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). Are you asking for a proof of that?

Comment: Hi. It is a rephrasing. But I don't want a proof of that theorem. I am trying prove this without using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Do you know about the [Jordan–Hölder theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jordan-HoelderTheorem.html)?

Comment: Yes; I read somewhere that the uniqueness of $u$ follows from Jordan-Holder theorem but I am not sure how. Specifically, if I have another mapping $v$ satisfying properties (1) and (2), how can I use Jordan-Holder to show $u=v$?

Comment: Well, you started your question with composition series of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and never came back to it. You might want to think about how composition series of that group actually look like.